# React useEffect dependent on value which is initialized after api has been called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My api returns an object of the following type:

```
type TApiReturn = {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string;
  d?: string;
};
```

Now, after having received the data, I want to pass part of it through to a child component.

```
type TChildComponent = {
a: string;
c?: string;
};
```

What I thought would work:

```
const [allData, setAllData] = React.useState<TApiReturn>();
const [childData, setChildData = React.useState<TChildComponent>();

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await api.get('myDataPath'); //this works, not part of it
      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

and then, to update the child component data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let parsedData: TChildComponent;
    parsedData.a = data.a;
    
    if (data.c) {
      parsedData.c = data.c;
    } 
  
    setChildData(parsedData);
  }, [allData.a]);
```

But yeah, this cannot work, since at the Start, `allData.a` is `undefined` at the beginning.

So to sum it up: I am unsure how to approach this situation. I understand that hooks do not have a callback function on purpose. But this situation seems to be quite normal, so there has to be a better design pattern to tackle this issue which I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since state should be immutable in React, instead of having a dependency array of `allData.a`, having just a dependency of `allData` could work (and then you can check if `allData` exists, and if it does, to compare `allData.a` against `childDate.a`).

But I think a better approach would be not to split the same data structure into multiple stateful variables, and just pass down `allData.a` when it exists, eg:

```
const [allData, setAllData] = React.useState<TApiReturn>();
// no childData at all

// ...

return (
  <Child a={allData?.a} c={allData?.c} />
);
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I try your suggested approach (passing the data down if it exists) I always get `Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532`.

Comment: What would you want to happen when the data might not exist yet and the child needs to be rendered?

Comment: Well I wrapped the entire component conditionally, {allData && <Child ...>}.

Comment: If it's rendered conditionally, it should be fine to just remove the optional chain, eg: `a={allData.a} c={allData.c}`

Comment: Well my linter complains either way. So far I was only able to workaround TS2532 by initializing the allData with  `null`. I gotta look into this, seems like an approach which will result in unwanted errors.
Also, how would I tackle this if I would not use conditional rendering?

Comment: What does the linter complain about when you remove the optional chain? It should be fixable. Conditional rendering is probably the best choice by far in this sort of situation.

Comment: The linter error was an error on my side, nvm.
Thank you for your help